# Why are numpy objects treated as global?

Tags: python, numpy

Why do numpy objects change globally if they've been changed in functions?

An example:

```
def some_function(b):
    b += np.arange(8)
b = np.arange(8)
some_function(b)
print(b)
```

Would change b even outside the function.

I am quite new to Python but I always thought of the principle 'what happens in a function remains in a function'. Is there a way to avoid the different behavior for numpy objects? What I was doing so far was always calling the function with a copy of the element (i.e. `some_function(b.copy()`) which seems quite strange.

Comment: This is typically how *all mutable objects work in Python*, because `obj += value` is essentially a call to `obj.__iadd__(value)`, which in the case of mutable objects, mutates them. This is no different than a `list`. Note, `int` objects are immutable, so this won't happen with `int` objects, or `tuple` objects (again, immutable).

Comment: "what happens in a function remains in a function" That just isn't true. If you mutate an object, then the object is mutated.. so, `def foo(x): x.append(42); x = []; foo(x); print(x)`

Comment: Much of your confusion is due to a misunderstanding of the relationship between objects and variables. You might want to [read up on that](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Note, **objects** are neither global nor local, *variables* are

Comment: Ahh, now I got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: For the particular example that you posted, you can avoid modifying the received array `b` by simply using operations that create new arrays, instead of modifying them in place, for example, doing `c = b + np.arange(8)`. Even if you do `b = b + np.arange(8)`, you will not be affecting the outer array, because you will be making the function-local variable `b` a reference to the new array created with `b + np.arange(8)`. This is confusing because one usually thinks of `b += a` as equivalent to `b = b + a`, but there is that important difference of modifying the object or making a new one.

Comment: Can you recommend an overview of which operations are in-place and which create a new obejct? Or how do I know?

Comment: By reading the documentation. There is no way to know, although, you should generally learn which types are *immutable* which would let you know that any method on them cannot mutate them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. It's technically `obj = obj.__iadd__(value)`. A subtle but important distinction. You can't increment a mutable tuple element without first assigning it to another name because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment to a variable, even if appears as an argument, makes it function-local

```
def foo(b):
    b = b + 123
    # return b  # required to see the change in b
```

Assignment to an element of object, if allowed, is a mutation.  That change will be 'visible' outside the function.

```
def foo(b):
    b[0] = b[0] + 123
```

This is true for `numpy` arrays and lists (and `dict`).  Strings, tuples and numbers will raise an error - they are immutable.  This may be closest thing to a 'universal' test for "in-place" mutability.

`+=` kinds of operations are more confusing.  Mutable classes change in-place; immutable create a new object.

```
 arr += 123         # numeric addition
 alist += '123'     # adds value to list
 atuple += (1,2,3)  # new tuple
 astr += '1243'     # new string
 anum += 12342      # new integer
```

Mutable classes like `list` have in-place methods

```
 alist.append(123)
```

Immutables don't have any (that I can think of).  `numpy` arrays don't have many in-place methods.  Most `numpy` methods and functions return a new array.  But arrays have a complication - the distinction between `view` and `copy`.

I could add that modifying the attributes of a class (where allowed) is a mutation, that does not affect the object's visibility outside the function.